# Moq.MockException: Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: x => x.Init()

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have this method which verify if a method is called. I am using xUnit and MOQ in C#.

```
    [Fact]
    public void VerifyIfInitCalled()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<ICal>();

        var cal = new Cal(mock.Object);

        // Act
        cal.Init();

        // Assert
        mock.Verify(x => x.Init(), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
```

and for my Cal class

```
public class Cal : ICal
{
    private ICal _cal;

    public Cal(ICal cal)
    {
        _cal = cal;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Init called"); ;
    }
}
```

But, I run the unit test, it fails with error `Moq.MockException : 
    Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: x => x.Init()` although I have called the `Init()` method.

Comment: `Init` is member of `Cal` class, there is no `Init` method invocation from `ICal` dependency, passed to constructor. `Init` method of mocked instance isn't called anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to modify your `Init()` to get your assert right

```
public void Init()
{
    _cal.Init();
    Console.WriteLine("Init called"); ;
}
```

and your interface `ICal` need to have an `Init()` member.

But clearly you have a conception problem you are implementing `ICal` and passing it into the class constructor !!.

**UPDATE**

A unit test is specific to an implementation so your test method need to test the `Cal` class.

If your class call an other service and you need to mock and setup a method call to get specific result you will use `moq`

Comment: So if my `Cal` implement `ICal`, I need to another another class just for that?

Comment: You don't need to pass the ICal interface in the constructor. Check my update to the answer